# conda lists latest version of cutadapt as 2.6 but only runs cutadapt 2.4

Tags: python, conda

Conda lists the most current version of cutadapt as 2.6 but when I check the version and run the program it only uses the older cutadapt v2.4

I've installed cutadapt using conda 4.7.12:
conda install -c bioconda cutadapt

When I do conda list it says I have the latest version of cutadapt:
cutadapt                  2.6              py36h516909a_0    bioconda

When I do which cutadapt it points to the right place:
/path/to/miniconda3/envs/myenv.2/bin/cutadapt

But when I do cutadapt --version it lists an older version:
2.4

Can anyone help me get the latest version of cutadapt up and running using conda?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own problem.  It seems I had installed cutadapt using both conda and pip at some point.

When I did 'pip list' I saw cutadapt v2.4.  So I removed this version of cutadapt 'pip uninstall cutadapt'.

Now when I do 'cutadapt --version' the last version installed using conda is shown as '2.6'.